# "Какой-такой павлин-мавлин..."

Tags: лексика

Думаю, все помнят фразу из мультфильма о приключениях Мюнгхаузена: "Какой-такой павлин-мавлин, не видишь, мы кушаем". Я живу в Крыму, где много тюркоязычных людей и часто сталкиваюсь с такой манерой изменять слова, причем, им это кажется безумно смешным. При этом армяне утверждают, что подобное явление в языке пошло от них. И евреи не отстают.
Хотелось бы узнать, откуда вообще взялась такая манера, и в чем, собственно, ее смыл?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В любом просторечном (или маскирующемся под него) разговоре, независимо от национальности беседующих, обязательно встретятся образцы подобных переиначиваний самых разных слов. Это и народная игра в рифму, и ироничное отношение к предмету, и нарочито-детская интонация... Вместо нейтрального звукоряда слова могут добавляться всем известными экспрессивно-нецензурными **морфами**. Смысл всего этого : наполнить (малограмотную/некультурную) речь примитивным юмором, для оживляжа.